# exclude values from a string or dictionar in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am consulting the databases of a mongo cluster and I need it to show me all the databases except some of them
this way i get the databases in dictionary form:

```
for db in myclient.list_databases():
    print(db)
``
`
and the output is as follows:
{'name': 'databasetest', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}
{'name': 'databaseQA', 'sizeOnDisk': 98304.0, 'empty': False}
{'name': 'databaseprod', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}
{'name': 'databasestage', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}
{'name': 'database2021', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}
{'name': 'database2022', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}



I would need the result to be all the db except:
{'name': 'database2021', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}
{'name': 'database2022', 'sizeOnDisk': 32768.0, 'empty': False}

how can i do it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like this. This will be creating a new list named filtered_dbs that doesn't have the DB names you specified.

```
filtered_dbs = [db for db in myclient.list_databases() if db['name'] not in ['database2021', 'database2022']]

for db in filtered_dbs:
    print(db)
```